# SpringKafka handling retry failures

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We consider using spring kafka [non-blocking retries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic). Everything is quite straightforward and looks nice: if exception is thrown inside annotated `@KafkaListener` method, configured `KafkaTemplate` sends failed message to predefined retry topic. But one thing that I didn't find - what happens if sending to retry topic fails for some reason (temporary connectivity issue with broker, for example), how we should handle errors inside retry mechanism? So far I found only tuning [Producer retries](https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/kafka-producer-retries/), but perhaps there is better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the send fails, normal (blocking) retry logic applies; by default, the error handler will perform a seek so that the failed record will be redelivered.

Comment: Verified on real env, and it works exactly as you described. Looks like committing offset on source topic happens only after committing offset on retry topic